# Get keycloak users based on their effective roles

Tags: keycloak

I have a list of realm roles and each realm role is having some client roles as composite role. When i create a user with a realm role, I get the client role as effective role.

When I try to list all users having a particular client role the user is not listed since the role is in effective role and not in assigned role.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried this endpoint? `GET /{realm}/users/{id}/role-mappings/clients/{client}/composite`

Comment: i want to get the list of users having a effective role not a single user

Comment: There's no capability even to load users by role in the Rest API: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-1902 You'd probably have to load the whole user set and check their roles.